# Is it possible to run nginx automatically on every startup in a docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm new to docker.

I'm setting up nginx server to serve static files inside a docker container. I'd like to enable nginx to start automatically on every startup inside a docker container.

I've tried changing ENTRYPOINT, CMD and crontab when building DockerImage. But these settings to run nginx on every startup works only the first time I "run" a container. When I "stop" the container and "start" it again, nginx does not start automatically inside the container.

I'm looking for a way to start nginx on every startup of a container and my first question is "is it possible to do this?"

My second question is about a container cycle. Given that there are not many discussions on this subject (all discussions are about automatically running a script or sth else at the moment of "run"), I wonder if it is more efficient to "run" and "kill" a container each time than just "stopping" and "starting" a container.

Here are the lines of code I tried for DockerImage (with crontab), which was my first try.

```
RUN apt-get install -y cron
COPY run_server /etc/cron.d/run_server
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/run_server
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/run_server
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

`run_server` is a simple crontab config file which includes:

```
@reboot service nginx start
```

Since this was not the solution I was looking for (it worked only when I "ran" a conainer, not "stopped" and "started" a container) I tried with supervisor, too.

```
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor && \
  mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor && \
  mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d
ADD supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.conf
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.conf"]
```

`supervisor.confg` contains:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:run_server]
command=/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/server.py
autostart=true
directory=/home
redirect_stderr=true
```

But neither of them worked the way I wanted ..

Comment: Can you just enable it in your docker file doing something like `RUN sudo systemctl enable nginx`, `RUN sudo service nginx enable` or similar? I guess you could also add a small bootstrap script which will be called on startup which in turn simply will do `sudo service nginx start`.

Comment: Could you please share your docker configuration, like Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: @Cyclonecode I will try this one. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to update my docker file and enable the `nginx` service so it will be started during the next reboot.

Here is a couple of different ways:

```
RUN systemctl enable nginx
RUN service nginx start
```

Another way would be to add a bootstrap script that starts the service:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service nginx start
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Make sure the `bootstrap.sh` is executable i.e `sudo chmod +x bootstrap.sh`.

Then update your docker file:

```
COPY boostrap.sh /bin/.

CMD ["bootstrap.sh"]
```

Comment: I've just tried your solutions, but it works only the first time I "run" a container and does not work when I stop and restart the container.. By the way, I guess the third line was to be RUN service nginx START, and not enable..? Thank you for your help though

Comment: @jay671 added another approach as well not sure if it will work though.

Comment: I mean to keep it running you might need to end the bootstrap script with something like you did before e.g `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

my Dockerfile , container ( CentOS 8 and nginx ) linux mint 19.3  Docker version 19.03.4

```
# howto:   Dockerfile
# CentOS 8 and nginx  
#  docker build -t centose .
#  docker run -it -p 80:80 centose
#    curl localhost 

FROM centos:latest
# MAINTAINER їван 
RUN yum -y install nginx 
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
#WORKDIR /usr/sbin/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply that using docker [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

you can simply set it when creating the container or updating the created ones
examples: `docker run -t -d --restart unless-stopped nginx`
to update the created ones: `docker update --restart unless-stopped {container ID}`